# Jssor add/remove slide dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I have a slider already rendered and then the user makes a change on a drop down causing an ajax request.

Based on the result I need to remove the current slides and add new ones. Can be more or can be less.
Any ideas on how to achieve this? I would like to avoid removing the entire slider and creating it again, seems like an overload to me.

I also have bullet navigation and will expect them to be refreshed too.

Regards,

Sergio

Comment: The workaround for the moment is jssor_slider1.$Pause(); $("#slider1_container").remove();

Comment: We should add $Add/$Remove api, but this feature is not ready yet.

Comment: :( will remove and rebuild the DOM. Thanks